# Distributed SOA structuring & designing

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, soa, restful-architecture

So basically I am currently planning a relaunch of an already established product. The product currently is just based on one big chunk and I want to divide it into single services, which can be scaled separately. I have already been digging around for a while, but I couldn't find any good inputs on how to structure/design a SOA application correctly.

With the example of a login, would the following setup be a correct/acceptable way to handle a login?

- Web Service, which handles basically all incoming traffic
- Account Service, which handles user authentication

[image: User login service example]

Now the flow would be the following:

1. A user reaches the web service, which provides the login UI
2. The user enters eMail and password, clicks on "log in"
3. The web service sends a `POST` request to the account service, which is published on `account.example.org/api/`
4. The account service validates the credentials and returns the result to the web service

Is this an acceptable way of handling/structuring services in SOA (really simplyfied). If yes, how do I authenticate services with other services, which won't be exposed/accessible publically to the web (like the account service)? Basic Auth? Or through an auth server?

Should I have everything on something like `api.example.org` instead of each service on a different subdomain (like `account.example.org/api/`) with the corrisponding `/api/` endpoint? If yes, how can I handle heavy loads or how can I scale parts of the services instead of the whole API?

What else is important to keep an eye on?

Of course I would also appreciate any recommandations for readings about the designing of distributed SOA API's

Answer (score 1):

That workflow draft seems ok at a glance, but the subject is pretty broad and not trivial to cover in a simple single post.

- yes, Basic Auth can certainly be one way to go once you get past
  registration;
- I see no need for subdomains at this point, but rather individual api endpoints like:
  `api.example.org/account` or `api.example.org/order`
- apart from deploying your api on multiple machines (a web farm which would scale your whole api), you can fall back on caching for calls querying big data; obviously the account scenario isn't a good example, but if you're going to have lots of requests here, they're likely to extend to other parts of the api; one exception would be the security attack trying to brute force user login, in which case you can set up some sort of captcha mechanism on the web service, plus some protection for your api (reject connections from the same ip past a certain threshold, for example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem why I wanted to use different subdomains is the following: how else would i be able to have different apis on different machines? Therefor I would basically need a Proxy or something like that which then routes api.example.org/{resource} to an internal domain?